# Switch Statement Orphan Error

Tags: java, switch-statement

i'm new to java and i've been learning about switch statements and I've hit a road bump ,

so far this is the code i have :

```
   public class Continents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int continent = 4; 

    swtich (continent) {

      case 1 : System.out.println("North America: Mexico City, Mexico");
                     break; 
      case 2 : System.out.println("South America: Sao Paulo, Brazil");
                     break; 
      case 3 : System.out.println("Europe: Moscow, Russia");
                    break; 
      case 4 : System.out.println("Afirca: Lagos, Nigeria");
                break; 
      case 5 : System.out.println("Asia: Shanghai, China");
                break; 
      case 6 : System.out.println("Australia: Sydney, Australia");
                break;
      case 7 : System.out.println("Antartica: McMurdo Station, US");
                break;

      default : System.out.println("Undefined continent!");
                break;
    }  




    }
}
```

however i keep getting the error

```
 Continents.java:8: error: orphaned case
  case 1 : System.out.println("North America: Mexico City, Mexico");
  ^
```

i understand what an orphan case is but i don't get how my code has one since i have declared the case inside the switch statement?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well `switch` is misspelled. Once that's fixed, it compiles fine for me.

Comment: is that a typo in your code? `swtich` instead of `switch`?

Comment: Check your spelling ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo .. `switch` and not `swtich`.

Hence that indicates no beginning of switch case which implies orphaned cases (i.e cases without any switch)

Once that is fixed, it compiled with no errors.

```
public class Continents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int continent = 4; 

    switch(continent) {

      case 1 : System.out.println("North America: Mexico City, Mexico");
                     break; 
      case 2 : System.out.println("South America: Sao Paulo, Brazil");
                     break; 
      case 3 : System.out.println("Europe: Moscow, Russia");
                    break; 
      case 4 : System.out.println("Afirca: Lagos, Nigeria");
                break; 
      case 5 : System.out.println("Asia: Shanghai, China");
                break; 
      case 6 : System.out.println("Australia: Sydney, Australia");
                break;
      case 7 : System.out.println("Antartica: McMurdo Station, US");
                break;

      default : System.out.println("Undefined continent!");
                break;
    }  
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac Continents.java 
$ java Continents
Afirca: Lagos, Nigeria
```

Answer (score 0):

you've misspelled `switch` as "swtich"